# Saving data to the database after signup

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create a database with firebase after a user is signed up.
I have this method:

```
writeUserData(mUID, mNickname){
    console.log("WRITE");
    firebaseRef.database().ref('users/' + mUID + '/').set({
      nickname: mNickname,
    });
}
```

From my understanding, my database should look something like that (after this method runs):

```
{
 users:{
     UID:{
       nickname
     }
  }
}
```

but after running this method, my database still null. Should I create a file or should it be created automatically after .set() happens?

I really got confused with Firebase and hope you guys could help me somehow.

Comment: By default the Firebase Database is configured to only allow authenticated users to read/write. To detect whether you're hitting an authorization error, use the approach described here: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/24459/detecting-errors-when-writing-a-value-in-javascript#t=20170708155105890558

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks, but I don't won't the user to write. I want the write action to be triggered when a user is signing up. Is it still considered that the user is 'writing' to the database?

Comment: if the React Native code writes to the database, that is a user write. Simply put: if the code runs on the user's device, it runs as that user. If you want that, you need to either sign the user in or allow anonymous writes (`".write": true`). If you want to trigger the code in a more trusted environment, consider using [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). There's an example of [handling when the account is created](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/email-users) (but that won't have a value for the nickname of course).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you, I will have a look.